# Is it possible to make deployer's incoming directory as symbolic link?

Tags: web8, configuration, deployer

I' m setting up Content Deployer of Web 8.
When I tried to make "incoming" directory as symbolic link, error occured when starting Content Deployer.
Is it possible to make deployer's incoming directory as symbolic link?

My cd_deployer_conf.xml is following.

"/usr/local/wcm-web8/deployer/incoming" is a symbolic link.

```
<Queue>
    <Location Path="/usr/local/wcm-web8/deployer/incoming" WindowSize="50" Workers="30" Cleanup="true" Interval="2s"/>
    <Location Path="/usr/local/wcm-web8/deployer/transactions" WindowSize="30" Workers="30" Cleanup="true" Interval="30s"/>
</Queue>
<HTTPSReceiver MaxSize="1000000000" Location="/usr/local/wcm-web8/deployer/incoming" InProcessDeploy="true"/>
```

Error log of Content Deployer is following.

```
2017-04-18 01:07:08,268 ERROR SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'binaryStorageSelector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.sdl.delivery.configuration.ConfigurationException: Binary Storage directory does not exist and could not be created
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686) ~[spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320) ~[spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
        at com.sdl.delivery.service.ServiceContainer.main(ServiceContainer.java:43) [service-container-core-8.1.1-1017.jar:8.1.1-1017]
Caused by: com.sdl.delivery.configuration.ConfigurationException: Binary Storage directory does not exist and could not be created
        at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.binarystorage.FSBinaryStorageAdapter.setup(FSBinaryStorageAdapter.java:77) ~[deployer-binary-storage-8.1.1-1024.jar:8.1.1-1024]
        at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.binarystorage.FSBinaryStorageAdapter.configure(FSBinaryStorageAdapter.java:48) ~[deployer-binary-storage-8.1.1-1024.jar:8.1.1-1024]
        at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.binarystorage.BinaryStorageSelector.configure(BinaryStorageSelector.java:52) ~[deployer-binary-storage-8.1.1-1024.jar:8.1.1-1024]
        at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.configuration.ChildConfigurationHolder.init(ChildConfigurationHolder.java:40) ~[deployer-config-8.1.1-1024.jar:8.1.1-1024]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:300) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: /usr/local/wcm-web8/deployer/incoming
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:88) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:384) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:674) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:781) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:727) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.binarystorage.FSBinaryStorageAdapter.setup(FSBinaryStorageAdapter.java:75) ~[deployer-binary-storage-8.1.1-1024.jar:8.1.1-1024]
        ... 25 common frames omitted
```

Regards,

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like a permissions issue to me. If the deployer cannot see the symlink, i expect whatever​ user it is running as doesn't have permission.

The deployer is probably accessing the folder through standard Java APIs and should respect the symlink.

Disclaimer: never tried this myself.

Comment: I modified owner of the both symbolic link and liked directory to a user which runs Deployer, so I think it's not permissions issue. Anyway I'll try again by changing owner and permission.

Answer (score 3):

I have given a quick try by creating both soft and hard symbolic links and it works fine with SDL Web 8 deployer in my environment

Looking at your below error line,

```
java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: /usr/local/wcm-web8/deployer/incoming
```

Please check once again whether you have created a symbolic link mistakenly to point to a file rather than to a folder

Comment: I was thinking this could also be caused by the deployer attempting to create the directory

Comment: My symbolic link points to a directory, and owner of the symbolic link and the pointed directory is same as Deployer's user, they have full permission(rwxrwxrwx). Still Deployer fails to start.

Comment: Can you please @Rajesh confirm the jdk version you are using, to give sense on my answer?

Comment: I'm using jdk1.8.0_65.

Comment: jdk 1.8.0_66 64 bit, good point to check whether OP has installed all the latest deployer hotfixes in his environment

Answer (score 1):

There is a known problem with certain versions of the Java virtual machine where this exception is thrown.

So my recomendation is to `update to JDK 8` and preferably the latest version, because there are certain versions of the JDK 8 in which this problem still exists.

Digging the problem, it seems to not be a problem with, cause the symlink is a file:
"`FileAlreadyExistsException is thrown if the file exists and is directory. In this example then the file exists but is a sym link so the exception is correct`." So it seems the solution has to be in the tridion side, changing the deployer behaviour. I don't know if it exists any hotfix related to this problem.